# How to Avoid Gui Lock

Tags: c#, user-interface, gtk#

I'm developing a Desktop application. I have a button that upon click calls some webservices.

Problem is when there is no connection or on a slow connection the interface becomes unresponsive and it seems as if the application crashed.

Wonder what are the techniques to get around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to investigate multi-threading.

By creating a thread and performing the processing on that you'll keep the UI responsive.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3es4b6yy%28VS.71%29.aspx) for a starting point.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can make asynchronous calls to the web service.  This means that the GUI doesn't wait for the response.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a thread to make the WS requests, and keep the interface thread free and responsive. You should notify the user when waiting by displaying an appropriate message and a progress indicator.
[Here](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/gtk-sharp-list/2007-March/007935.html)'s something specific to GTK# UI update.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [BackgroundWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/BackgroundWorker_Threads.aspx) class for calling a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

I asked something very similar myself. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080353/please-help-me-make-this-code-thread-safe).

BackgroundWorker is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this FAQ (and answer)](http://gtk-sharp.sourceforge.net/faq.html#3.5), especially the talk about GTK+'s "idle" system.